# How to change background of UIButton in Xamarin.iOS depending on state without using a sub-class UIButton?

Tags: c#

I am using a UIButton. I want to change the **background color of UIButton Xamarin.iOS** in Highlight and Normal state.

I want to change background of UIButton in Hightlight state and to set transparent color when UIbutton in normal state